# Is there any way to create AnimateSprite Sheet from AndEngine as in COCOS 2D?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, andengine

Everyone,
       Can anyone help me to know is there anyway to create AnimateSprite Sheet from AndEngine as in COCOS2D.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about COCOS2D except it appears that Nicholas is working on adding/porting it to AndEngine. See his GitHub page here - https://github.com/nicolasgramlich - and check out some of the extensions that he is working on.

Comment: Okay let see..and thx for ur kind response

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
    AnimatedSprite runner = new AnimatedSprite(0, 0, mRunner);
    // Animate with 100 milliseconds each frame, start at frame 0 and go through 
    // frame 3, set to true for looping otherwise false for no looping.
    runner.animate(new long[] { 100, 100, 100, 100 }, 0, 3, true);
    scene.attachChild(runner);
```

and in onLoadResources()

```
    this.mRunnerTexture = new Texture(512, 128, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
    this.mRunner = TextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mRunnerTexture, this, "gfx/runner.png", 0, 0, 4, 1); // 4 columns and 1 row, a 4x1 animated sprite
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(this.mRunnerTexture);
```